# Writing Apache Beam Filter in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-beam

I'm writing an Apache Beam project, which is written is Java, using Scala and not able to identify the syntax required to use the Filter.by functionality. Here's an example of something I've tried,

```
    class Test extends SerializableFunction[String, Boolean] {
      def apply(m: String): Boolean = true
    }

    val pipeline = Pipeline.create();
    pipeline.apply(
      KafkaIO.read[String,String]()
        .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
        .withTopic("test-topic")
        .withKeyDeserializer(classOf[StringDeserializer])
        .withValueDeserializer(classOf[StringDeserializer])
        .withoutMetadata()
    )
    .apply(Values.create())
    .apply(Filter.by((m: String) => true))
//And I've tried this
    .apply(Filter.by(new Test()))
```

which give me the following error,

```
[error] example.scala:61:19: overloaded method value by with alternatives:
[error]   [T, PredicateT <: org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction[T,Boolean]](predicate: PredicateT)org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Filter[T] <and>
[error]   [T, PredicateT <: org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ProcessFunction[T,Boolean]](predicate: PredicateT)org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Filter[T]
[error]  cannot be applied to (com.example.Test)
[error]     .apply(Filter.by(new Test()))
[error]                   ^
[error] one error found
```

The documentation for Filter.by is here https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.2.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Filter.html#by-PredicateT-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you might be interested in [scio](https://github.com/spotify/scio), which is cleaner and clearer to use with Scala.

Otherwise, I've successfully created a `Filter.by` with the Java SDK by explicitly specifying the `ProcessFunction` type on the lambda (tested with Beam 2.16.0):

```scala
// Using test pipeline outside of a JUnit @Rule
val pipeline = TestPipeline.create
pipeline.enableAbandonedNodeEnforcement(false)

// Applying a filter.
val predicate: ProcessFunction[String, java.lang.Boolean] = m => m.length == 3
val output = pipeline.apply(Create.of("one", "two", "three"))
  .apply(Filter.by(predicate))
PAssert.that(output).containsInAnyOrder("one", "two")

// Run the test.
pipeline.run();
```

(Note the `java.lang.Boolean`, **not** `scala.Boolean` return type.)

Comment: Thanks for that. My miss was not using java.lang.Boolean. Also, I saw scio and it looks great, but i'm a little hesitant to simply adopt a wrapper around Beam because scio will always be a bit behind and and more importantly Spotify may decide to drop it. Or do you think those concerns are a bit unfounded?

Comment: Just an opinion: The scio devs are very involved with Beam, and features and ideas have flowed in both directions!  I would consider it low risk that scio would fall  behind beam releases, or be abandoned.   (Unfortunately, most of my Beam work has been in Java, so I've mostly admired scio from afar...)